# Target type of existing array-value doesn't match the new one (dynamic)

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I recently discovered the dynamic-Datatype and it's pretty useful at all for the project I currently work on.

Here is a little snippet of my code:

```
                    if (tempDyn != null)
                    {
                        termIndex[i] = tempDyn;
                    }
```

While termIndex is a dynamic-Array and tempDyn is of dynamic-Datatype. 
Before I assign termIndex[i] the Val of tempDyn, it already holds a value. Of type: String. tempDyn is of type object[] but I dont run any operation on the value which could be specific to a certain type.

When the assignment is taking place Runtime throws an exception:

**ArrayTypeMismatchException**
The exception that is thrown when an attempt is made to store an element of the wrong type within an array.

I initially thought this would be prevented by using dynamic-Datatypes but it makes sense, that the runtime forms the dynamic-Array to an array of type string[] when the first value is entered. (Split is ran first on termIndex)

Is there anyway to prevent this behaviour and to store the "odd" value in termIndex or would I need to work with further variables/dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array being of compile time type `dynamic[]` dos not ensure that the array can truly store any kind of value, it just means that the compiler will not do any type check, and that those will only be done at runtime.

An exemple:

```
dynamic[] array = new dynamic[2];    
array[0] = "blah";
array[1] = 1;
```

This will run just fine, `array` is instantiated as a "true" `dynamic[]`

Contrast this:

```
dynamic[] array = new string[2];    
array[0] = "blah";
array[1] = 1; // <-- throws an ArrayTypeMismatchException!
```

In this case, `array` really is a `string[]`. Storing it in a `dynamic[]` variable just skips the compile time type verifications, but will not magically allow you to store anything in the array.

---

As a general rule of thumb, you should limit your uses of `dynamic`. Dynamic variable are a little more expensive in terms of performance, but that's not the main point. The main issue is that by using dynamics where you don't really need them, you abandon all the help the compiler can provide you by statically typing the variables. You also lose nice things like intellisense or autocompletion.

`dynamic` is a nice feature when dealing with a source that is intrinsically dynamic,a json input for instance, but don't overuse it.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for, thanks! I didnt explicitly initialise the array as dynamic[dimension], as I overlooked I see that the result of Split is the first usage of the dynamic-Array. In that way it makes sense that it gets internally converted to string[]. It's a fail in my concept, but I know now how to fix it. Thanks for the advice for caution with dynamic also, i know where the flaws are but I try to Invoke-Functions on runtime with changing objects, therefore it is exactly what I need this time :) Next time I stick to traditional types again hehe. Have a nice dayy!

Comment: indeed, dynamic is a very good substitution to `Invoke` through reflexion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying.

Providing more of your code like the definitions of the variables would help to understand.

But for now it sounds more like you would want to use lists for instead of arrays.

```
var termIndex = new List<dynamic>();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I will surely give it a try also! That might be the solution though, if i can keep up with the objects i will try to do that first. Thanks to you to!!